# WordPress: auto refresh specific div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a shortcode which usually display scores and schedules of the game. My problem is i want to refresh that specific div #show with shortcode by not refreshing my whole page. Is there anyone can help me out with this situation because I'd search all over the Internet but nothing happens.

below is my `header.php` of my parent theme

```
<div id="show" class="little-head-2"><?php echo do_shortcode('[game-widget]');?></div>
```

See below my attach script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $('#show').load('#show');
}, 30000);
```

Please see below screenshot of my header

You can actually visit the site: [http://aseanbasketballleague.com]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$j(function($) {
var SANAjax = function(){
  $('#show').fadeOut("slow").load('www.test.com').fadeIn("slow");

}
setInterval(SANAjax, 10000 );  ///////// 10 seconds 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: <script>
$j(function($) {
var SANAjax = function(){
  $('#show').fadeOut("slow").load('aseanbasketballleague.com').fadeIn("slow");

}
setInterval(SANAjax, 10000 );  ///////// 10 seconds 
 });
</script>

nothing happens